# Flutter WEB PDF creation not updating data on Sencond or further call to Function

Tags: flutter, pdf, flutter-web

well basically What I do is to create a PDF on client side with flutter web. It works seamlessly the first time, but on a second call or third it is not creating a new document. Actually it increase the by one the PDF pages yet the information remains the same that I got the first time I run. Unless I refresh the page (F5).  What I basically do, is receive as named params some information, like ID, Date, Businesname, etc etc etc. I'm Using pdf: ^1.3.24 plugin to perform this taks.

next is my code:

```
 import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:pdf/pdf.dart';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

var pdf = pw.Document();

Future CreatePDF(
    {ImageUrl, datePlaced, mainOrder, subOrderID, businessName}) async {
  http.Response response = await http.get(
    ImageUrl,
  );

  final Uint8List list2 = response.bodyBytes;
  final image2 = PdfImage.file(
    pdf.document,
    bytes: list2,
  );

  final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/small_logo.png');
  final Uint8List list = bytes2.buffer.asUint8List();
  final image = PdfImage.file(
    pdf.document,
    bytes: list,
  );

  final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/qr_50.jpg');
  final Uint8List list3 = bytes3.buffer.asUint8List();
  final image3 = PdfImage.file(
    pdf.document,
    bytes: list3,
  );

  //Create a PDF document.
  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.letter,
      build: (pw.Context context) {
        return pw.Center(
          child: pw.Column(
            children: [
              pw.Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  pw.Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 75,
                    child: pw.Image(image2),
                  ),
                  pw.Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 75,
                    child: pw.Image(image3),
                  ),
                  pw.Container(
                    height: 75,
                    width: 75,
                    child: pw.Image(image),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 15),
              pw.Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Orden ID: ',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  pw.Text(
                    '${subOrderID}',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              pw.Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: pw.MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    '${mainOrder}',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10,
                      background: pw.BoxDecoration(color: PdfColors.yellow),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 10),
              pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Fecha de Recepción de Orden: ',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(),
                  ),
                  pw.Text(
                    '${datePlaced}',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Comercio Responsable: ',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                  pw.Text(
                    'Nombre de Comercio',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Text(
                    'Si su comercio emite Factura, debera emitirla a: ',
                    style: pw.TextStyle(),
                  ),
                  pw.Container(
                    decoration: pw.BoxDecoration(
                        // border: pw.BoxBorder(color: PdfColors.blue,width: 6),
                        ),
                    child: pw.Column(
                      children: [
                        pw.Text(
                          'Razon Social',
                          style: pw.TextStyle(),
                        ),
                        pw.Text(
                          'NIT321566',
                          style: pw.TextStyle(),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 15),
              pw.Row(
                children: [
                  pw.Text("Esta Orden Requiere de los siguientes items: "),
                ],
              ),
              pw.SizedBox(height: 30),
              pw.Text("Probando"),
              pw.Text("Probando"),
            ],
          ),
        ); // Center
      },
    ),
  ); // Page

  List<int> bytes = null;
  bytes = pdf.save(); //Save the document

  //Download the output file
  AnchorElement(
      href:
          "data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,${base64.encode(bytes)}")
    ..setAttribute("download", '${subOrderID}.pdf')
    ..click();
}
```

and this are captures of the inital proces before download, the document run the 1st time, and the second

[The box has all the information that is passed to the function that creates the PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itdh3.png)

[This is the PDF generated the 1st time, notice that there's only one page in document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNMEG.png)

[And this is the 2nd time, notice that pages now are 2 y If run the process again it'll increase. BTW, tha next pages are blank.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38ZZf.png)

I really appreciate any help. I feel that the problem is generated since the pdf document, is note getting disposed or closed... or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Move the document initialization "pdf = pw.Document();" into the CreatePDF function.
2. If there is strill a problem try deleting the document file before continuing